# Is there an injective operator with a dense nonclosed one-codimensional range?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, linear-transformations

Let $H$ be an infinite dimensional separable Hilbert Space.

Is there an operator $A\in B\left( H\right) $ such that $Im\left(
A\right) \neq \overline{Im\left( A\right) }=H$, $ codim\left(Im%
\left( A\right)\right) =1$
and
 $\ker \left( A\right) =\left\{ 0\right\} $ ?

Comment: Is there a such a thing as a dense one-codimensional subspace?

Comment: yes It exists. For example, take the kernal of a non-continuous linear finctional. this kernel is a subspace of one codimension.

Comment: Do you mean that $\operatorname{codim}(\overline{\operatorname{Im}(A)}) = 1$?

Comment: no, I mean that codim(Im(A))=1

Comment: @DjalalOunadjela I don't think that the closure of such a kernel will ever be $H$.

Comment: It will be and in fact it's a characterization: a non-trivial functional is unbounded iff its kernel is dense

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no such an operator. More generally, a continuous operator on a Banach space with finite dimensional kernel and cokernel must have a closed image (such operators are called Fredholm). Let me prove this for your specific case. Let $A \colon H \rightarrow H$ be continuous, injective and $\dim H/\operatorname{Im}(A) = 1$. Choose $v \notin \operatorname{Im}(A)$ and note that $\operatorname{Im}(A) + \operatorname{span} \{ v \} = H$. Consider the map $\tilde{A} \colon H \oplus \mathbb{C} \rightarrow H$ given by $\tilde{A}(h,z) = Ah + zv.$ This map is one-to-one, onto and continuous so by the open mapping theorem, it has a continuous inverse $\tilde{A}^{-1} \colon H \rightarrow H \oplus \mathbb{C}$. By the definition of the external direct sum, $H$ is a closed subspace of $H \oplus \mathbb{C}$ and then $\tilde{A}(H) = \operatorname{Im}(A)$ is closed. This proof works verbatim if you consider more generally an injective continuous linear map $A \colon B_1 \rightarrow B_2$ between Banach spaces with codimension one cokernel.

Answer (score 2):

Take $V$ to be a non-closed subspace of $H$ with codimension $1$.  Because of the codimension, we know that there exists a basis (an infinite, Hamel basis) for $V$ which can be extended into a basis for $H$ by adding a single vector.  These bases for $V$ and $H$ have the same cardinality.  So, there must exist a bijective linear map from $H$ to $V$.

---

If you mean $\operatorname{codim}(\overline{\operatorname{Im}(A)}) = 1$, there is indeed such an operator.  Take $H = \ell^2$ and
$$
A[(x_n)] = \left(0,\frac {x_1}1,\frac{x_2}2,\frac{x_3}3,\dots\right)
$$
The image of $A$ is non-closed, but its closure is $\{(x_n): x_1 = 0\}$.

Comment: Thank you so much, but what I am looking for is an operator A such that codim(Im(A))=1.

Comment: @DjalalOunadjela how do you define the codimension of a non-closed space?

Comment: @DjalalOunadjela also, if a post fails to answer your question, don't click the checkmark, as that signals that you're satisfied with the answer.  You can click it again to "unaccept".

Comment: the codimension of a subspace is the dimension of its complementary.

Comment: See my latest edit.

Comment: thank you so much. But it remains to make this linear mapping continuous, that is A belongs to B(A).

Comment: @DjalalOunadjela ah, you did say $B(H)$.  I don't think there exist dense subspaces with codimension $1$, though.

Comment: Of course it exists. For example, take the kernal of a non-continuous linear functional. This kernel is a subspace of one codimension.

Comment: @DjalalOunadjela but can such a subspace be dense in $H$?

Comment: @DjalalOunadjela wait... you're right.  That's obvious now

Comment: yes, the kernel of a linear functional, is either closed (if the functional is continuous) or dense (if the functional is discontiuous) and in both cases it has codimension 1.